# Second finger triggers touchesMoved in SingleTouch-View

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, touch

I want to create a small drawing application for children. I do not want to implement a multitouch drawing application so I set: multipleTouchEnabled to false for the drawing view.

The drawing works ok so far, but when the kid touches the view with a second finger the touchesMoved-eventhandler of the view is called:

```
- (void) touchesMoved: (NSSet *) touches withEvent: (UIEvent *)event{
        UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
        CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInView:self];

    //Draw a line from the last touchPoint to here…

}
```

By this when the kid touches the screen with a second finger a line is drawn from the first finger to the second finger which is not intended.

Is there any way to prevent this?

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this problem also.  You will either have to

A) Make a check that only allows a touch to be moved a certain distance.

B) Cancel all touches when a second touch is detected (re-enable multipleTouch)

Otherwise, a second finger in single touch mode looks the same as a moved touch to the system.

Comment: Thx for the fast reply borrrden. Is there any way that I can distinguish between the first touch an touches that were made after that?

Comment: Well, the way I do it is by keeping a touch count (increment it in touches began, and decrement it in touches ended / cancelled).  If it goes above 1 then you know you have a 2nd touch.  However, it is difficult (maybe not possible) to keep track of individual touches.  I do faintly remember a method, but I might be remembering Android.

Comment: Thx I just save the Pointer of the first UITouch now and compare it with the touches I get in touchesMoved. By this I can distinguish between touches that were made after the first. When touchesEnd is called for the first touch I just release the pointer. This seems to work OK for me. Thx again for your help. :-)